# D3.js axis tick conditional formatting

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to get my ticks on my axis to have conditional formatting. For example, if their positive numbers I want them to be green and red if they are negative numbers.

```
var bonus_penalties = [ -1,-13,-5,0,5,10,15];

var bpAxisScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,6])
    .range([bottom- 45, 45]);

var bpAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(bpAxisScale)
    .orient('right')
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return bonus_penalties[d]});

var bp_axis = d3.select("#experienceView").append('svg:g')
    .attr("transform", "translate(160,0)")
    .attr('class', 'bp')
    .call(bpAxis)
    .style('fill',  function(d) {
            if(bonus_penalties[d] < 0){
                return 'red';
            } else {
                return 'green';
            }
    });
```

Comment: Select the `text` elements after calling the axis component and then apply the style as in your code.

Comment: What would be the best way to add icons to the ticks? For example locked or unlocked icons?

Comment: I'd say you'd have to modify the axis component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lars Kitthoff gave the answer:

```
bp_axis.selectAll("text")
    .style('fill',  function(d) {
        if(bonus_penalties[d].key == 0){
            return 'black';
        } else if(bonus_penalties[d].key < 0){
            return 'red';
        } else {
            return 'green';
        }
    })
    .attr('font-size',"10px")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can translate to [modern Javascript syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), but with some care, using [conditional chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and all  in human-readable format:

```
bp_axis.selectAll("text")
    .style('fill',  d =>
        (bonus_penalties[d].key < 0)? 'red'
        : bonus_penalties[d].key?     'green'
        : 'black'
    )
    .attr('font-size',"10px")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle");
```